# restructuring my ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service

Currently I'm working on a rails app and it consists of two parts: the client and server.

So every time the client makes a call to the server, the server returns some json documents. I put all the business logic(most of them are fetching the data from db and converting their format) into the helpers at the server side and the controllers call helper methods directly. Then the helpers grow crazily after I've made many changes. At this time I have to refactor my code base.

Then, I'm wondering for these business logics(fetching and converting data) shall I split them all into isolated modular services or still keep some logic in the helpers and put the rest into services? If it's the latter one, which should remain and which should be moved away?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your code as well?

Answer (score 1):

The currently dominant view on that is that you put your business logic into your models (so it resides on the server side). Controllers primarily focus on working as endpoints and calling the right model methods.

When you find your models getting "too fat", i can recommend this article for you:
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/